# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se cumpla un segundo condicional que depende de un primer condicional y de la variable escogida?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles

En este caso, el usuario debe escoger un producto (burguer) para realizar el pago según lo que haya escogido. En el primer ciclo, del if... else if... todo bien. El problema es en la función comprar cuando el usuario escoge determinado producto y lo multiplica siempre por el precio de la variable burguer pero existen dos variables mas (burguer2 y burguer3) de precios distintos que allí es donde no se como aplicar la condición para que pueda multiplicar por la variable correcta en la función comprar.

```
let burguer = 500;
let burguer2 = 600;
let burguer3 = 700;

function ingresaburguer() {
    let tipoBurguer = prompt("ingrese el tipo de burguer que desea");
    if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "SIMPLE") || (tipoBurguer == "simple"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer simple es " + burguer)
    } else if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "DOBLE") || (tipoBurguer == "doble"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer doble es " + burguer2)
    } else if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "TRIPLE") || (tipoBurguer == "triple"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer triple es " + burguer3)
    } else {
        alert("Error: ingrese tipo disponible")
    }
    return tipoBurguer
}

let tipoBurguer = ingresaburguer()


function compra(cantidad,burguer) {
    return cantidad * burguer
}
let cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de burguer que desea"))
let total = compra(cantidad,burguer)

alert("su total es " + total)


function vuelto() {
    let vuelto = parseInt(prompt("ingrese en numero, con cuanto dinero va a pagar"))
    return vuelto
}
let cambio = vuelto()
alert("su vuelto es " + (cambio - total))
```

Comment: Supongo que es parte de tu proceso de aprendizaje, por lo cual te pregunto, ¿puedes o sabes usar alguna estructura como Objetos y/o Arrays?

Comment: Si, @mauricio-contreras, estoy practicando. Sé cómo utilizar los arrays y su concepto. El problema es que para este ejercicio es solo con condicionales y por eso mi dolor de cabeza. Sin embargo, si consideras que es solo con arrays la mejor manera, hazme saber la respuesta para practicar de una vez arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola pues te hace falta que guardes en la variable

> tipoBurguer

le pasas el valor de la hamburguesa, prueba de esta manera:

```js
let burguer = 500;
let burguer2 = 600;
let burguer3 = 700;

function ingresaburguer() {
    let tipoBurguer = prompt("ingrese el tipo de burguer que desea");
    if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "SIMPLE") || (tipoBurguer == "simple"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer simple es " + burguer)
        tipoBurguer = burguer;
    } else if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "DOBLE") || (tipoBurguer == "doble"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer doble es " + burguer2)
        tipoBurguer = burguer2;
    } else if ((tipoBurguer != "") && ((tipoBurguer == "TRIPLE") || (tipoBurguer == "triple"))) {
        alert("el precio de la burguer triple es " + burguer3)
        tipoBurguer = burguer3
    } else {
        alert("Error: ingrese tipo disponible")
    }
    return tipoBurguer
}

let tipoBurguer = ingresaburguer()


function compra(cantidad,burguer) {
    return cantidad * burguer
}
let cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de burguer simple que desea"))
let total = compra(cantidad,tipoBurguer)

alert("su total es " + total)


function vuelto() {
    let vuelto = parseInt(prompt("ingrese en numero, con cuanto dinero va a pagar"))
    return vuelto
}
let cambio = vuelto()
alert("su vuelto es " + (cambio - total))
```